# Class, constructor, confusing directions

Tags: python, class, methods, constructor, initialization

"Create a class that holds an apartment number, bedrooms, baths, and rent amount. Create a constructor that accepts values for each of the data fields. Also, create a get method for each field. Write an application that creates at least five Apartment objects. Then prompt the user to enter a minimum number of bedrooms required, a minimum number of baths required, and a maximum rent the user is willing to pay. Display data for all the Apartment objects that meet the user’s criteria." I try to create get methods, but then whenever I try using it I get errors.

```
Potential Input: 1000, 1, 1
Desired Output: 
Aparment#  Rent   Rooms  Bathrooms
111        1000   1      `1
class Apartments:
     def __init__(self, apartNum, rent, rooms, bath):
        self.apartNum=apartNum
        self.rent=rent
        self.rooms=rooms
        self.bath=bath

     def setRent(self,aRent):
        self.rent1 = aRent
     def getRent(self):
        return self.aRent

     def setRoom(self,rooms):
        self.room = rooms
     def getRoom(self):
        return self.rooms

     def setBath(self,baths):
        self.bath = baths
     def getBath(self):
        return self.baths

apt_1= Apartments(111,1000,1,1)
apt_2= Apartments(112,2000,2,1)
apt_3= Apartments(113,2500,2,2)
apt_4= Apartments(114,3000,3,2)
apt_5= Apartments(115,3500,3,3)

rentInput=input('Enter maximum amount of rent: ')    
roomInput=input('Enter minimum number of bedrooms: ')
bathInput=input('Enter minimum number of baths: ')
```

Comment: Ahhh definitely another "Java in Python" class. But if you are getting errors, please provide the *full error message*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you consistently use the same variable names,  in `__init__` you store `self.rent`, then in the next two methods you store `self.rent1` then try to access `self.aRent`.  You do comparable invalid accesses for your other variables.

This is how it looks with all the instances of inconsistent variable access that I saw cleaned up.

```
Potential Input: 1000, 1, 1
Desired Output: 
Aparment#  Rent   Rooms  Bathrooms
111        1000   1      `1
class Apartments:
     def __init__(self, apartNum, rent, rooms, bath):
        self.apartnum=apartNum
        self.rent=rent
        self.rooms=rooms
        self.baths=bath

     def setRent(self,rent):
        self.rent = rent
     def getRent(self):
        return self.rent

     def setRooms(self,rooms):
        self.rooms = rooms
     def getRooms(self):
        return self.rooms

     def setBaths(self,baths):
        self.baths = baths
     def getBaths(self):
        return self.baths

apt_1= Apartments(111,1000,1,1)
apt_2= Apartments(112,2000,2,1)
apt_3= Apartments(113,2500,2,2)
apt_4= Apartments(114,3000,3,2)
apt_5= Apartments(115,3500,3,3)

rentInput=input('Enter maximum amount of rent: ')    
roomInput=input('Enter minimum number of bedrooms: ')
bathInput=input('Enter minimum number of baths: ')
```